# Аналог Python генераторов на C++

Tags: python, c++

Можно ли как-то *заставить* `C++` код работать как-то схоже с кодом на `python`, который называются **генераторы**, "не изобретая при этом новую Теорию Относительности".

Например, последовательность Фибоначчи:

```
def fib():
    f = 1
    s = 0
    while True:
        yield s
        f, s = s, s+f

k = fib()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(k))
```

Пробовал так, но, думаю, что есть какие-то более "правильные" варианты ?

```
int fib(){
    static int f=1, s=0;
    int t=f;
    f = s;
    s += t;
    return s;
}

int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        cout << fib() << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Как минимум, мой аналог "одноразовый" (нельзя начать последовательность заново).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например так (с созданием экземпляра объекта и использованием оператора вызова функции):

```
class Fib {
public:
    int operator()()
    {
        int t = f;
        f = s;
        s += t;
        return s;
    }
private:
    int f = 1;
    int s = 0;
};

int main() {
    Fib k;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << k() << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

А я бы вот так сделал :) :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Fibonacci {
private:
    int first = 1;
    int second = 0;
    int index = 0;
public:
    int operator++() {
        int t = first;
        first = second;
        second += t;
        ++index;
        return second;
    }
    int operator--() {
        if (index <= 0) {
            index = 0;
            first = 1;
            second = 0;
            return second;
        }
        int t = second - first;
        second = first;
        first = t;
        --index;
        return second;
    }
};

int main() {
    Fibonacci fib;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout << ++fib << " ";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
        cout << --fib << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0 0 0
```

Можно добавить всякие функции по типу `getByIndex` всякие преобразования и т.д. Так же можно сделать класс шаблонным и тогда использовать длинные числа ну или например `ullong int`. Всякие проверки на переполнения сделать можно.

Comment: спасибо за такой интересный пример.

Answer (score -1):

В недалеком светлом будущем (а пользователям Visual Studio уже сейчас, если включить поддержку *Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft*) можно будет использовать более каноничные генераторы (с использованием ключевого слова **co_yield**):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>
#include <experimental/generator>

std::experimental::generator<double> fibonacci(const double ceiling) {
    double j = 0;
    double i = 1;
    co_yield j;
    if (ceiling > j) {
        do {
            co_yield i;
            double tmp = i;
            i += j;
            j = tmp;
        } while (i <= ceiling);
    }
}

int main() {
    for (const auto v: fibonacci(100))
        std::cout << v << ' ';
}
```

(пример собирается в Visual Studio 2019, с включенным *Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft*, выводит числа Фибоначчи в диапазоне от нуля до ста)

Comment: ух ты, удобная "штука" появляется в си